# What are Cordova/Phonegap splashes in www/res/screen/ios for?

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

Cordova keeps two sets of splash images, one in ProjectName/Resources/splash and the other one in www/res/screen/ios. Why is that and why not use the same set for everything? What is the one in www/res/screen/ios for?

Comment: This is a good question, and like so many things with cordova there is no documentation.  I'm guessing www/res/screen/ios will contain the assets for multiple environments, ios/android/.. and there will be some tooling to generate the ios/android/.. specific assets from them.   Is there a place to read about this, and other updates?

Comment: Did you find any updates on this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @Red2678 - unfortunately no..

Answer (score 4):

The files in What is the one in `www/res/` are not being used in the iOS project.

You can remove them if you wish.

It looks like they might be use in the future to update the ones that are located in ProjectName/Resources/ with some sort of script.

Answer (score -1):

This is some reading:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen

The images you find in your www/res/screen/ios is for the start up loading image your app will have.

However, do keep in mind that a lot of people experience that the splash screen only will live for a certain amount of time, and then it will turn black, until your app is done loading.

This can be because of:
1) Heavy HTML, JS and CSS code
2) External files such as CSS and JS
3) Slow smartphone
4) .. Might be :)

I hope i could help :)

Comment: Thank you for answering but I do know what a splash screen is. The thing is, Cordova keeps two sets of them (the same images appear twice in the same project) and my question is: "why is there two sets?", not why is there a splash screen in Cordova at all..